# How to share AVD system images for others to use for Android 13

Tags: android-source, android-automotive

I've built an AVD system image by following these steps:

```bash
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android13-release --partial clone  
repo sync  
lunch sdk car_arm64-userdebug  
make  
make emu_img_zip
```

And everything was built successfully. However, I want to share my AVD system image so that anybody can download it from their Android Studio so I followed these steps.

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/avd#sharing_avd_system_images_for_others_to_use_with_android_studio

And I am a bit confused. When I host my `sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].zip` file  and provide the link for the said file inside the SDK Update Sites, I get an error that reads:

`Content is not allowed in prolog`

And I can't see the file listed inside the SDK Platforms tab.

Should I also have the `sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].xml` file and if so, what should that file look like?

**Note**: When I was following these steps for Android 12 everything worked fine, but I am aware that the build process differs for Android 13 and higher.

In Summary:

I tried hosting my `sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].zip` file and providing the link to the file in the Sdk Update Sites tab on Android Studio.

I was expecting to see the system image inside the SDK Platforms tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and found the following answer that helped me:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244956535#comment24

Not sure if the xml is supposed to be generated somewhere but if you just create it manually with the following content, you should be able to get it to work (copied from the linked comment):

**sys-img.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdk:sdk-sys-img
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01">
    <remotePackage path="system-images;android-33;sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug;x86_64">
        <type-details xsi:type="sdk:sysImgDetailsType">
            <api-level>33</api-level>
            <tag>
                <id>android-automotive-playstore</id>
                <display>sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug-mybuild</display>
            </tag>
            <abi>x86_64</abi>
        </type-details>
        <revision>
            <major>1</major>
        </revision>
        <display-name>sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug-mybuild</display-name>
        <archives>
            <archive>
                <complete>
                    <size>UPDATE_THIS_BYTES</size>
                    <checksum type='sha1'>UPDATE_THIS_SHA1</checksum>
                    <url>sdk-repo-linux-system-images-UPDATE_THIS.zip</url>
                </complete>
            </archive>
        </archives>
    </remotePackage>
</sdk:sdk-sys-img>
```

After updating the fields with your own values, you can open the sdk manager and add `file:///path/to/sys-img.xml` as your custom update site.

Hope that helps